# Send 2 Dimensional Array to Web API Servcie

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I have a table of strings in my web app. It's a 2 dimensional array in Javascript. I would like to send them to a C# Web API call so I can put them into a file and mail out to someone as CSV.

How do I post a 2 dimensional JSON object to a Web API method? What do I have to put in my jquery AJAX call and what should my method signature be in the Web API controller?

Comment: Can you show us anything at all ?

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution is to send data as it is (a Json array) and parse it in C#, as explained here: [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c)